# Use values of a certain key in an array of object as keys

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to define types so that the type of `Row` depends on the **values** provided in `Column`.

For example

```
type Column = { key: string; title: string };

type Row = {
  // ??
};

const table = (columns: Column[], rows: Row[]) => {};

table(
  [
    { key: "firstName", title: "First Name" },
    { key: "address", title: "Address" },
  ],
  [{ firstName: "mKman", address: "1 First St" }] // how to enforce this ?
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order capture a type for use somewhere else, you need [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```
const table = <T extends readonly Column[]>(
  columns: T,
  rows: Record<T[number]['key'], string>[]
) => {};
```

Here the type of the array of `columns` objects is captured as `T`.

Then `rows` uses that type. Indexing an array type by `[number]` gets the type of the array members. And then indexing that by `['key']` looks up the property named key on those objects.

In the case of your example:

```
T[number]['key']
```

Would be of type:

```
"firstName" | "address"
```

You can now make a `Record` type with that union of string literals as keys, that have `string` as the value type.

```
Record<T[number]['key'], string>
```

---

You also need to make sure you pass in your schema `as const` in order to capture the string literal types, instead of just `string`.

---

Putting all that together:

```
type Column = { key: string; title: string };

type Row<T extends readonly { key: string }[]> =
  Record<T[number]['key'], string>;

const table = <T extends readonly Column[]>(
  columns: T,
  rows: Row<T>[]
) => {};

table(
  [
    { key: "firstName", title: "First Name" },
    { key: "address", title: "Address" },
  ] as const,
  [
    { firstName: "mKman", address: "1 First St" }, // fine
    { lastName: "mKman", address: "2 Second St" }, // error
  ]
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=20&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2UC8UDeUDWEIAXFAM7ABOAlmgOYDcUw1wCEpFN9UAvgwFgAUMNCQoAJTgB3ADwAVKBAAewCGgAmZKJQgBDDXDQIQuAkU5VadPgG0AugD4swqJIgBjOJQ0LbaVAAjCEp7WwByQhBw+wAacit6R0ERIS80CmY9QPYsKAUlVXUtHX1DY1N4ZHQHRwAKVygvaozSeVjGyhkyUik5eUcHYQBKLGccfmFRbPYGoTdbRrc8KNIAIgAzakoKADk9FAg1+JY2Dig1gDFtzP3Dtb4O+bczVYuDDV0yMmPmVnZ1gBBDSfCDfB68J5uexQPTadIUKFQRbPZZQLY7YB3c5rFAAaRQejQvw+Xx6FwAjFBrpioABlYAQ+IAemZ6NoECWZgQcKxBxx+MJxPipLB5LWACZ6Z4jBp6YzHlBWUpKF1KI17CMUkA)

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, you need to infer each `key` property of each column:

```js
type TableColumn = {
  key: string;
  title: string
};


const table = <
  Key extends string,
  Column extends TableColumn & { key: Key },
  Columns extends Column[],
  Row extends Record<Columns[number]['key'], string>,
  Rows extends Row[]
>(columns: [...Columns], rows: [...Rows]) => {};

table(
  [
    { key: "firstName", title: "First Name" },
    { key: "address", title: "Address" },
  ],
  [{ firstName: "mKman", address: "1 First St" }] // ok
);


table(
  [
    { key: "firstName", title: "First Name" },
    { key: "address", title: "Address" },
  ],
  [{ address: "1 First St" }] // expected error, no firstName
);

table(
  [
    { key: "firstName", title: "First Name" },
    { key: "address", title: "Address" },
  ],
  [{ firstName:'John', addres: "1 First St" }] // expected error, addres is written with type, should be double ss
);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnK4Bm)

You can find more information about function argument inference in my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: Sir Captain-Yossarian on your profile you need to put, "To fight against Russian soldiers", because you are not fighting "With them", you are fighting "with Ukrainian soldiers for Ukraine".

Comment: Thank you for the answer  I wish you the best of luck in your struggle against the invaders